# How Can I Use Ternary Conditional Operator Without Else?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got a code block like this

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const newNumbers = numbers.reduce((acc, num) => {
  acc.push(num > 3 ? num : null);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log('new Numbers', newNumbers);
//returns new Numbers,[null, null, null, 4, 5, 6]
```

But I **don't want** null values to be pushed in array. I want to perform the action like this but without `if`:

```
const newNumbers = numbers.reduce((acc, num) => {
  if (num > 3) {
    acc.push(num);
  }  
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(newNumbers);
//returns new Numbers,[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use an `if`? You could use `&&` but it's not very readable if you do that imo.

Comment: You can't: the `? :` operator forms an _expression_, not a _statement_, and in JS (and most languages) all expressions **have** to evaluate to _some value_ (unless you want to ruin everything with `throw`, I guess...)

Comment: @NickParsons I tried it but it still pushes unwanted items in new array :/

Comment: Why are you using `reduce` instead of `filter` and `map`?

Comment: @Shifty You should use `.filter()` (as suggested in the below answer). The `&&` solution doesn't sit inside of the `.push()`, it would be `<condition> && arr.push(...)`, but it's not recommended to write code like that as you're writing an expression that isn't being used for it's result but rather just its side effects (more [details](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions)). It still isn't clear why you want to remove the `if` though. While `&&` works you should avoid it for side-effect code and instead favour an `if` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `?`,

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const newNumbers = numbers.reduce((acc, num) => {
  num > 3 && acc.push(num)
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(newNumbers);
```

//returns new Numbers,[4, 5, 6]

Comment: yes this one works thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> How Can I Use Ternary Conditional Operator Without Else?

No. The *conditional operator* always has to "return" a value. Imagine it was possible to leave out the alternative (e.g. `arr.push(num > 3 ? num)`), what value would be pushed to the array?

In this specific case there is a better tool for the job: `Array#filter`:

```
const newNumbers = numbers.filter(num => num > 3)
```

Comment: Yeap ```filter()``` works fine but I wondered if its possible to make it with ```reduce()``` too

Comment: Of course it is, you even included one possible solution in your question. But only because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do:

```
num > 3 ? acc.push(num) : {}
```

Comment: yes I tried but it adds empty objects too :)

Comment: @Shifty No. You must have tried `acc.push(num > 3 ? num : {})`, which is different from `num > 3 ? acc.push(num) : {}`